# Creating Waypoints in Autoware?? Creating .txt file

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS MELODIC

AUTOWARE VERSION: 1.12.0-alpha2

I would like to know how to create waypoints in Autoware such that Car follows that path shown by Waypoints. In demo video, they are using moriyama.txt file but **How do I create a custom .txt file for my own simulation??**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328387/creating-waypoints-in-autoware??-creating-.txt-file/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Waypoints can be created by launching the `waypoint_saver` node. Once you are localized, run `roslaunch waypoint_maker waypoint_saver.launch`. This will create a new file in `/tmp/saved_waypoints.csv`. Stop the launch file to stop recording. You can then load these waypoints with `roslaunch waypoint_maker waypoint_loader.launch multi_lane_csv:=/tmp/saved_waypoints.csv`.

**Note**: if you run `waypoint_saver` more than once without moving or deleting `/tmp/saved_waypoints.csv`, it will *append* to the file rather than replacing it. If you then try to load this file with more than one set of waypoints in it, the loader will fail.

**Note 2**: Autoware 1.12.0 has been officially released. I highly recommend using the released version instead of the alpha or beta.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0